# Error "Cannot find module './in-memory-data.service'"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-tour-of-heroes

I am following the Angular Tutorial (Tour of Heroes) but I am unable to finish the 7'th Tutorial regarding HTTP which simulates a web API using angular-in-memory-web-api. Everything is exactly how it is given in the tutorial. Still, I am getting this error. I am using WebStorm as my editor. I have spent several hours going through the answers to other similar questions but nothing solves my problem. I have already tried to reinstall the service and redo this step of the tutorial but nothing works.

Here is my in-memory-data.service.ts file:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }

  // Overrides the genId method to ensure that a hero always has an id.
  // If the heroes array is empty,
  // the method below returns the initial number (11).
  // if the heroes array is not empty, the method below returns the highest
  // hero id + 1.
  genId(heroes: Hero[]): number {
    return heroes.length > 0 ? Math.max(...heroes.map(hero => hero.id)) + 1 : 11;
  }
}
```

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroSearchComponent } from './hero-search/hero-search.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    // The HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule module intercepts HTTP requests
    // and returns simulated server responses.
    // Remove it when a real server is ready to receive requests.
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
    )
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally, my package.json if it can help you resolve my problem:

```
  "name": "angular-tour-of-heroes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.11.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Can you share plunker or something to reproduce the same?

Answer (score 0):

just keep following the tutorial. InMemoryData service will be generated in the next part of the tutorial.[check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0MqV.jpg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29991893)